# How to prevent WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT from being reported in console input buffer?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console, windows-console

In the following code example, why is it that `WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT` records are being reported in the console's input buffer? To reproduce, resize the console window by dragging its left or right edge and you'll see the events printed to the console.

According to the documentation, the `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT` flag must be passed to `SetConsoleMode` to enable the reporting of `WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT`. The example below disables all flags.

Anyway, I know I can just ignore the events and not do anything with them, but it bothers me when the Windows API documentation says to expect one behavior but I observe a different behavior. Am I missing something? Or is this perhaps a bug in Windows or maybe just incorrect documentation?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro (Version 1903, OS Build 18362.720).

**Relevant Links**

[SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode)

[ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput)

[INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)

[Reading Input Buffer Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events)

**Code example**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    // turn off all flags
    SetConsoleMode(hInput, 0);
    INPUT_RECORD inputRecord;
    DWORD eventsRead;
    while (ReadConsoleInput(hInput, &inputRecord, 1, &eventsRead)) {
        printf("EventType: %x\n", inputRecord.EventType);
    }   
}
```

**EDIT**

This same problem was referenced in a Microsoft Terminal GitHub thread back in 2018:
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/281#issuecomment-440463031

"Task ID: 19686633 - Ensure that events for window buffer sizing and viewport sizing respect ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT flag"

Comment: This is life in platform software APIs.  They evolve and wise developers will use defensive coding practices to insulate themselves, as you could do by coding your handler to check that the event it received is actually the one it intends to handle.  Unless you are doing maintenance on a purely legacy application, you cannot count on perfect, eternal documentation, and what kind of career is that?

Comment: Thanks @BobHy. That makes sense. I don't spend a lot of time in the Windows API, but occasionally I mess around with it for fun. When I do I often encounter weird things like this... and most of the time it's me not doing something right because I'm not fully understanding the documentation. I expected that would be the case with this, but perhaps `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT` is disregarded in the latest Windows API.

Comment: Hi, you said that the `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT` flag **must be** passed to `SetConsoleMode` to enable the reporting of  `WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT`. Can you share me the doc link?

Comment: In the SetConsoleMode doc (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode), the `dwMode` parameter description says "When a console is created, all input modes except ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT are enabled by default." Also, in the doc for `WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/window-buffer-size-record-str) it says "Buffer size events are placed in the input buffer when the console is in window-aware mode (ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT)." That makes it sound like if the flag is NOT specified, then buffer size events will NOT be put in the input buffer.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT "Task ID: 19686633 - Ensure that events for window buffer sizing and viewport sizing respect ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT flag" commented on Nov 20, 2018 (https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/281#issuecomment-440463031)

Comment: @RichardGieg Frome the doc you provided, it does not state that without the `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT` flag, `WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT` cannot be reported. If there are any misunderstandings in the documentation, I suggest you can post a new thread about the problem in the github.